# Issue with deploying docker image to kubernetes

Tags: java, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD HelloWorld.class HelloWorld.class
RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre   
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","HelloWorld"]
```

Following this google cloud tutorial https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

I have successfully created image and push.

But once I run this

```
kubectl run hello-app --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-world:v1
```

Its giving error **CrashLoopBackOff** on pod. Can any one help me to run this image on kubernetes?

Comment: can you describe the pod and paste the output?

Comment: I am not sure if document is missing some info. This command run my job kubectl create -f testm1.yaml but not the kubectl run. For pod output I am just getting "CrashLoopBackOff" in kubectl run

Comment: the kubectl run command just creates a deployment using the image you provided. CrashLoopBackOff means the pod keeps crashing once it is created. 
Check your kubernetes logs (event log or use Stackdriver) to try and find out why. You can also try running the container on another VM using docker directly to make sure the image is running. This might be an issue with how you are building your image

Comment: You should also be able to compare the two deployments to see what differences there are between the one created using the run command vs the one created from your YAML